# How can I put an white logo image with a transparent background in a black header?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to see an actual logo in my header, rather than a white rectangle.

I have a Rails application with a black header about 100px high. I have a white brand logo with a transparent background.

Also using Bootstrap. When I put the image in the header, all I see is a white box. Sure, the image is probably there, but you can't see it.

I have the image setup with an id of "brand-image":

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
      <%= image_tag 'My-logo-PMS-C-REV.png', id: "brand-image" %>
    </a>
```

CSS is:

```
#brand-image{
  height:50px;
  background-color:black;
}
```

I can never figure out even the simplest CSS. CSS has proven to always be extremely difficult and non-intuitive for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the inverted navbar? It has a black or almost black background to start with

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-inverted

```css
.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #222;
  border-color: #080808;
}
```

The non-inverted version has an almost white background listed. 
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-brand-image

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-color: #e7e7e7;
}
```

Are you using any bootstrap themes?

The surrounding `<a>` tag is probably large than the image and is why the id on the image does not seem to have any effect; but I would need to see the page to determine absolutely.

Can you provide a link to the image or a larger sampling of the header code?